# Unable to execute my hash table correctly/ SAS

Tags: sas, hashtable

I have a data step before the code below called "simulation_tracking3", that outputs something like:

```
CDFx Allowed_Claims
.06   120
.12   13
.15   1400
```

I want my hash table to average the Allowed_Claims based on a randomly generated value (from 0 to 1). For example, let's call this **Process A**, if Px = rand('Uniform',0,1) yields .09, I want it to average between the Allowed_Claims values where Px = .06 and Px = 0.12, which is (120+13)/2

The role of the array is that it dictates how many iterations of Process A I want. The array is

```
Members {24} _temporary_ (5 6 8 10 12 15 20 25 30 40 50 60 70 80 
                                    90 100 125 150 175 200 250 300 400 500);
```

So when the loop starts, it will perform 5 iterations of Process A, thereby producing 5 averaged "allowed_claims" values. I want the sum of these five claims.

Then, the loop will continue and perform 6 iterations of Process A and produce 6 averaged "allowed_claims" values. Again, I want the sum of these 6 claims.

I want the output table to look like:

`

```
Member[i]    Average_Expected_Claims
   5              (sum of 5 'averaged 'claims) 
   6              (sum of 6 'averaged' claims) 
   8              (sum of 8 'averaged' claims)
```

The code that I currently have is below. My errors occur here:

> ```
> do rc = hi_iter.first() by 0 until (hi_iter.next()_ ne 0 or CDFx gt rand_value);
> ```
>
> `rc = hi_iter.prev();`

The error says, respectively:

> ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &,
>   *, **, +, -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, ><, >=, AND, EQ, GE, GT, IN, 
>                 LE, LT, MAX, MIN, NE, NG, NL, NOTIN, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.

Blockquote

> ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the
>   COMPILATION phase.

```
data simulation_members;                            *simulates allowed claims for each member in member array;  
            call streaminit(454); 
                array members [24] _temporary_ (5 6 8 10 12 15 20 25 30 40 50 
                                                60 70 80 90 100 125 150 175 200 250 300 400 500);  *any number of members here is fine;
                if _n_ eq 1 then do;                        * initiliaze the hash tables;   
                if 0 then set simulation_tracking3;                     * defines the variables used; 
                declare hash _iter(dataset:'simulation_tracking3', ordered: 'a'); *ordered = ascending - do not need a sort first; 
                _iter.defineKey('CDFx');                    * key is artificial, but has to exist;
                _iter.defineData('CDFx','Allowed_Claims');  * data variables to retrieve;
                _iter.defineDone();
                declare hiter hi_iter('_iter');            * the iterator object;

                end;


                do _i_member = 1 to dim(members);            * iterate over members array;
                        call missing(claims_simulated);
                            do _i_simul = 1 to members[_i_member]-1;
                            rand_value = rand('Uniform',0,1);
                            do rc = hi_iter.first() by 0 until (hi_iter.next()_ ne 0 or CDFx gt rand_value);
                            end;
                            ac_max = allowed_claims; 
                            rc = hi_iter.prev();
                            ac_min = allowed_claims;
                            claims_simulated + mean(ac_max,ac_min);
                 put rand_value= claims_simulated=;                                             *just for logging;
                end;    
            putlog; 
            output;                                                                              *drop unnecessary columns; 
            end; 
            stop;
            run;
```

Comment: `hi_iter.next()_` seems wrong.  `_` is not normally allowed in that context.

Comment: what could a possible solution be? Ultimately I want rc to find the "next" term. Thanks Joe!

Comment: Remove the `_` so it's not a syntax error?

Comment: My original line of code that you're using here:  `do rc= hi_iter.first() by 0 until (hi_iter.next() ne 0 or px1 gt rand_value );`  Note that there's no `_` after `hi_iter.next()`.

Comment: Joe, coming in clutch again. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Joe, if I wanted to see the the individual values that are being summed up for each group, how would I do that? For example, for the 5 group person, if I wanted to see the averages that are being used?

Comment: `put` them to the log during the iteration; I actually did that initially before cleaning up my debugging, for example.

Comment: where does this go? I tried after the `claims_simulated + mean(ac_max,ac_min);` line

Comment: You would need to store `(mean(ac_min,ac_max))` in a variable and then put that, I think, if that's what you mean (the average of the two).  But yes, that's the right spot.

Comment: hey Joe, the last iteration for each item in the array (5th iteration of the 5th person, 6th iteration of the 6th person,..., 500th iteration of the 500 person group) uses the same random value as the iteration before it.

Comment: In the 5 person group, the 4th person and the 5th person have the same random value that they use.

Comment: Hey Joe, could you take a look at my question?

Comment: You mean they use the same pair of lower:upper values to impute with?  That will happen from time to time after all. Or do you mean you see identical values from RAND()?

Comment: They're completely identical! Also it doesn't perform a running total for the last iteration.

Comment: A workaround that I thought was to iterate '_i_simul = 1 to members[_i_members]' (which produces an extra row) and then somehow conditionally sum until it reaches the value of members[_i_members]. But it won't solve the inherent problem that it's copying and pasting the exact value for the last two rows

Comment: Why do you do it to -1?  I don't see that making sense to me. I didn't in my initial answer after all.

Comment: if I do it do members[_i_members], it would produce an extra row. There would be 6 rows for the first iteration (5 members)

Comment: I don't think so. Or at least the way I understand your problem it wouldn't.

Comment: I just ran the program again and it produced an extra row :/

Comment: What does that mean ?  You're not even putting out a row for each member of that loop. You mean in the log?

Comment: In the output "simulation_members", I'm getting 6 rows for the first iteration, 7 for the second, etc.

Comment: You don't have an output from the loop that I am talking about. So I don't see how it could do that unless you've confused something mightily.

Comment: I also modified the code to output each and every iteration. My apologies for not updating you on that

Comment: Well then you need to take away the other output statement.

Comment: In the output, I can see each generated claim per member per group

Comment: I posted an updated question if that'd be easier to see! I created what my output looks like there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500476/do-loop-random-number-is-generating-the-same-number-twice-and-isnt-adding-it